# pow(1, inf) == nan?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, nvidia

I noticed some strange behavior in one of my compute shaders where they would return nan unexpectedly.
When investigating closer I found `pow` to be the culprit:

`pow(1, inf) == NaN`

From a [C](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/pow)/[C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) standpoint I would expect `pow(1, inf) == 1`:

> pow(+1, exponent) returns 1 for any exponent, even when exponent is NaN

**Is GLSL's `pow` defined for this input?**

I only found the usual exceptions for `base < 0`, and `base == 0 && exponent <= 0` in the specification.

Comment: `1/0`, huh? division by zero? infinity seems like the proper result and NaN as the power of infinity would be impossible.

Comment: @Vallentin: I can only tell you what I am seeing. No compiler errors (or warnings) for 1/0 and the result of 1 from pow. If you have a better way to [create INF inside GLSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435253/glsl-infinity-constant) tell me about it.

Comment: division by zero doesn't need to throw an error as infinity is an accepted result. Thereby x^infinity again equals NaN which would be expected. What I'm saying is, I can't see what the problem is, as the result makes sense.

Comment: @Vallentin From a mathematical standpoint I would expect 1^infinity to be 1,  x^infinity for 0 <= x < 1 to be 0, and x^infinity for x > 1 to be infinity. The only place for NaN IMHO is negative numbers to the power of infinity.

Comment: True, though it might be because it can't represent the number and thereby gives NaN, why it doesn't give infinity I don't know. But that's actually a good question then.

Comment: @Vallentin: I removed the `1/0` part. I made the integer division error. For true INF values (1.0/0.0) the return value is consistently NaN. (It seems `1/0 == -1` in GLSL, so the expression was `pow(1,-1)` which is cleary 1).

Comment: @Nobody From a mathematical perspective, 1^Infinity is not 1. http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/56006.html

Comment: @nos: You are right, I totally forgot about the limit from other directions so I should not motivate this with maths. I expected GLSL to behave like [C](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/pow)/[C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) where cppreference.com states: `pow(+1, exponent) returns 1 for any exponent, even when exponent is NaN`.

Comment: Technically C++ does not require that at all, it's a [IEE754 pecularity](http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754/meeting-materials/2001-07-18-c99.pdf). And GLSL [doesn't do IEEE754](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12223539/15416)

Comment: @MSalters: Okay, so another region where the C++ standard gives leeway to the compiler writers? As to GLSL: your link does only reiterated what I already said. I took closer look at the specification and it states: `While
encodings are logically IEEE 754, operations (addition, multiplication, etc.) are not necessarily performed
as required by IEEE 754` and `Infinities and zeros are
generated as dictated by IEEE, but subject to the precisions allowed in the following table`. Those two citations are from 4.1.4 and 4.7.1 of GLSLangSpec.4.40 and (IMHO) no further relevant mentions of NaN are made.

Comment: Indeed, C++ doesn't require IEEE754 and often it's not (fully) implemented.

Comment: @MSalters: Stop destroying my orderly world view ;) Do you have some sources that state where common C++ implementations differ from IEEE?

Comment: Truncating denormals to zero is common, because the CPU doesn't support them in **real** hardware. They'll use microcode instead. Compilers optimizing a+b-b to just a. That kind of stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@Damon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31920002/760746) was close but copied a mistake from the spec:

```
pow(x, y) == exp2(x *  log2 (y))
```

Which has x and y swapped. It should be

```
pow(x, y) == exp2(y *  log2 (x))
```

(test e.g `pow(2, 3)`)

Using the correct formula we get

```
pow(1, inf) == exp2(inf * log2(1)) == exp2(inf * 0) == exp2(nan) == nan
```

Answer (score 2):

Although compute shaders kind of imply that you use a GPU and GLSL version (> 1.30) that does IEEE compliant floating-point math, this is not something you can take for granted, unluckily. So... here be dragons.

Your reasoning from a C++ point of view quoting the C++ reference is reasonable and correct, but it omits a small but important sentence: *"If the implementation supports IEEE floating-point arithmetic (IEC 60559),"*. This small sentence highlights that it's neither a C++ requirement (just a coincidence since IEEE 754 asks for it, and *usually* C++ implementations comply with IEEE), and it's not a strict guarantee either (it is perfectly allowable for a C++ implementation to *not* implement IEEE 754).

Further, GLSL *is not* C++. This may come as a surprise with arithmetic because although it obviously isn't the same language, one can expect that math still works the same, can't one?

Well, no. `pow(x, y)` is defined (although 8.2 on which the online man page is based does not explicitly say so) as `exp2(x*log2(x))` in GLSL. It inherits its precision from the forementioned expression as stated in 4.7.1. It is not stated that `pow(1, x)` equals `1`.

Now, expanding the above expression with the *presumably correct* intermediate results, the correct result should be `+INF`, since `log2(+INF) = +INF`, and `1*+INF` is still `+INF`, and `exp2(+INF) = +INF`.
But, the standard doesn't really define that. It only explicitly (un)defines zero exponents.

Comment: Just stumbled on this exact (`exp2(x*log2(y))`) passage in the [spec](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.40.pdf#page=94). Damn, just another thing to trip over.

Comment: Now that I think about it I realize that your answer explains why `pow(1, inf) == INF` in GLSL but not why it is NaN as in my question.